# How to join this query based on condition?

Tags: sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have a query like below to join 6 table.

```
select     usr.userid,usr.firstName,usr.middleName,usr.lastName,nuser.GRAND_FATHER_NAME,nco    untry.NAME_AR,ncountry.NAME_EN,ncase.START_DATE 
from  User_ usr 
inner join TBL_NAFETHAH_USER nuser 
On nuser.USER_ID = usr.userId 
inner join TBL_NAFETHAH_COUNTRY ncountry 
on nuser.NATIONALITY = ncountry.ID
inner join TBL_NAFETHAH_CASE ncase 
on usr.userId = ncase.inmate_id 
inner join TBL_NAFETHAH_CASE_STATUS ncasestatus 
ON ncase.CASE_STATUS_ID = ncasestatus.CASE_STATUS_ID
and ncasestatus.CASE_STATUS IN (1,2)) 
inner join TBL_NAFETHAH_CASE_STAGE ncasestage 
on ncasestage.CASE_STAGE_ID = ncase.CASE_STAGE_ID                   
inner join TBL_NAFETHAH_USER_IDENTIFICATION uident 
on ( (usr.userId = uident.USER_ID and uident.ID_TYPE = 1) or (usr.userId = uident.USER_ID and uident.ID_TYPE = 2) )   
inner join TBL_NAFETHAH_LOOKUP_VALUE nlookup 
on nlookup.LOOKUP_KEY = uident.ID_TYPE 
and nlookup.CATEGORY_ID = 9
inner join TBL_NAFETHAH_LOOKUP_VALUE nlookup2 
on nlookup2.LOOKUP_KEY = ncasestage.CASE_STAGE 
and nlookup2.CATEGORY_ID = 15
where  nuser.MAKE_PUBLIC = 1
```

I want to put one more condition in this line

```
         inner join TBL_NAFETHAH_USER_IDENTIFICATION uident on ( (usr.userId = uident.USER_ID and uident.ID_TYPE = 1) or (usr.userId = uident.USER_ID and uident.ID_TYPE = 2) )
```

If this condition does not met, ie empty `(usr.userId = uident.USER_ID and uident.ID_TYPE = 1) or (usr.userId = uident.USER_ID and uident.ID_TYPE = 2)`m then I have to add another condition `(usr.userId = uident.USER_ID)` and if it returns muliple row only take first row.

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to omit missing records from the TBL_NAFETHAH_USER_IDENTIFICATION table then `INNER JOIN` a sub query that returns the first record that meets the criteria with a useful **ORDER BY**.

```
inner join 
(
    SELECT TOP(1) * FROM TBL_NAFETHAH_USER_IDENTIFICATION uident 
    WHERE usr.userId = uident.USER_ID  --AND ID_TYPE IN(1, 2)
    ORDER BY ID_TYPE 
)
uident ON usr.userId = uident.USER_ID
```

If you want to include records without a match from the TBL_NAFETHAH_USER_IDENTIFICATION table then `LEFT OUTER JOIN` a sub query that returns the first record that meets the criteria with a useful **ORDER BY**.

```
left outer join 
(
    SELECT TOP(1) * FROM TBL_NAFETHAH_USER_IDENTIFICATION uident 
    WHERE usr.userId = uident.USER_ID ID_TYPE IN(1, 2)
    ORDER BY <SomeValue>
 )
 uident ON 1=1
```

**NOTE** : If there will always be a record in the  TBL_NAFETHAH_USER_IDENTIFICATION for each user then you can order by ID_TYPE and take the first row. If 1 and 2 are the first two values in ID_TYPE, this will guarantee that if there is a type of 1 or 2 then it will come first. If you have a type of 0,-1,A, B, etc, then you will have to add a virtual rank column via another sub query.